C++: enforce a function argument is consteval
I would like my API to enforce that certain function parameters are compile-time constants. I have made a template wrapper
template<class T>
class ConstEval {
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    consteval ConstEval(Args&&... args) : obj(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    T& operator*() {
        return obj;
    }

    const T& operator*() const {
        return obj;
    }
private:
    T obj;
};

Which I can then use to wrap a parameter eg
// print() only accepts compile-time constant strings
void print(ConstEval<std::string_view> sv) {
    std::cout << *sv << "\n";
}

void test() {
    print("foo"); // compiles ok

    std::string bar("bar");
    print(bar); // error - call to consteval function is not a constant expression
}

This seems to do exactly what I want. My question is: is this a sensible way? Is there something simpler?
Edit: the use-case is for using a string value as a dimension in a metrics pipeline. Making it a compile-time constant ensures there is a fixed upper bound on the number of possible dimension values.

Is this for a design-constraint, or performance? For performance, this won't help at all, in fact it will make things worse on certain ABIs when a call cannot be inlined. The design-case, would appear odd to me - wouldn't be bad if you tried to share a bit of your real use-case, as std::string_view is mainly used to make the exact origin of argument being passed in irrevelant.

IMHO sensible would be either make the function constexpr if you are okay with it possibly running at run time or make the whole function consteval make make it 100% compile time.

Thanks @NathanOliver, unfortunately neither of those are acceptable. I have added the use-case to the description.

@Juliean thanks, it's a design concern, I added the use-case to the description

If the function is marked consteval, every parameter must be constexpr. I don't understand the question.

@Red.Wave I have a non-consteval function, and I want to ensure that one of its parameters is only ever called with a consteval argument.

Put the compile time arguments in template argument list.
